# How to make toggle hidden by default

Tags: jquery

Hello I would like to know how to make toggle hidden when the page loads, I have made a simple code, but when the page loads it will be shown by default. I want it the way around.

I have to tried to use CSS something like

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

when I use this code, the element doesn't show at all.

this is my code

*EDITED*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function toggleDiv(divId) {
  $("#"+divId).toggle();

  }
 </script>
```

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">this is a test</a>
   <div id="myContent">
      <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContentt');"><span>this is a text</span></a>
          <div>this is a test #2 </div>
   </div>

          <div id="myContentt">
            test
          </div>
```

please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess, you want something like this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krY56/1/) ( I used `onclick` in demo because jsfiddle doesnt like javascript on `href`)

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{
       display:none;
    }
```

**Markup:**

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">this is a test</a>
<div id="myContent" class='hidden'>
  <div>this is a test #1 </div>
</div> 
<br />
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContentt');"><span>this is a text</span></a>
<div id="myContentt" class='hidden'>
 this is a test #2
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#"+divId).toggle(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add the

```
$("your class").hide();
```

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subResult").hide();
});

then you can define your function
 function toggle(){
$(".subResult").slideToggle(2000);
     }
```

**Another Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("p").hide();

  $("button").click(function(){

    $("p").toggle();

  });

});
```

///////

`$("p").hide();`  This line hides your div on ready function.

Comment: he's hiding an element by its id though. This approach assumes that there's only one element, hidden by default, that we need to toggle.

Comment: you might run into problems with this, if you refresh the page. You should set a default value in your CSS code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toggleClass('hidden')` to show and hide your elements.

Comment: Replace .toggle() with the above code, also make sure the elements in question already have the "hidden" class.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to understand with toggle() is that it simply toggles the CSS display attribute. Therefore, if you want to replace one element with another, simply make sure the element you want initially hidden has a style of `display: none;` . When you use the toggle() method, it will make the visible element hidden with a `display: none;` and will remove that attribute from the hidden element.