# Code works in W3shool test page but not in Joomla

Tags: toggle, show-hide

I am testing this code and it is working here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_debugger  but not on my Joomla page. The Chrome console error is at the bottom of the post

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button</a>
<div id="myContent" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;">
    The content in this div will hide and show (toggle) when the toggle is pressed. 
</div>
```

63-tet.html:168 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of nulltoggleDiv @ 63-tet.html:168(anonymous function) @ VM4704:1

I have cheched the source page and my code is sent back to me by the server untouched:

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button</a>
<div id="myContent" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;">
    The content in this div will hide and show (toggle) when the toggle is pressed. 
</div>  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Joomla is filtering/ black-listing certain keywords. You can see that it is trying to call the function:

nulltoggleDiv and access the toggle property of that.

If you press f12 and search for "toggleDiv" you should be able to see the actual html after it has been deformed.

Check out this document:

https://docs.joomla.org/Help16:Content_Article_Manager#Filtering_Options_.28HTML.29

from doc:

```
Black List Filters
The default filter method in Joomla! is 'Black List'. The default 'Black List' contains the following tags to exclude:

'applet', 'body', 'bgsound', 'base', 'basefont', 'embed', 'frame',   'frameset', 'head', 'html', 'id', 'iframe', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'name', 'object', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'xml'
The default 'Black List' contains the following attributes to exclude:

'action', 'background', 'codebase', 'dynsrc', 'lowsrc'
You can 'Black List' (disallow) additional tags and attributes by adding to the Filter tags and Filter attributes fields, separating each tag or attribute name with a space or comma. If you select a Filter Type of "Black List", this list will always be used, plus any additional tags and attributes you add.
```

Comment: It does not seem to be that, the source code of the page shows that my code is there, see above. Interesting that, if you press "run" above you can see an error but I can not make sense of it (I am at beginner level with these)

Comment: The code works fine when I press run and click toggle the button. It hides and reveals the div as expected.

Comment: Some times I get this https://i.imgur.com/bi1dqTe.png when I refresh the page, which is similar with my error

Comment: I have also tested this code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960753/how-to-make-toggle-hidden-by-default  and I receive a similar error. I suspect it is because the way  $("#" + divId) is interpreted. The divId is being passed correctly ...

Comment: It is definitely Joomla but I do not know how to isolate the issue. I have tested the code on a stand alone page

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be with this reference

```
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
```

After I replaced the above with

```
  var element = document.getElementById(divId);
   element.toggle();
```

the code worked