# How To Hide Toggleable Text By Default With JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm new to using Jquery and I need to hide some sample text by default. The idea is a user can click on a play as shown below and a brief description of the play would pop up. By clicking on the title of the play again, the text would disappear. Right now, the text is showing up by default. I need it to be hidden to start and only appear when the name of the play is clicked. [The website currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pu0a.png)

HTML code used:

```
                            <h3>Tragedies:</h3>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        
                            <div class="play">
                                <h5 class="rnj">Romeo and Juliet -- Saturday June 4th at 7PM</h5>
                                <p class="rnj"><br>test text</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="line">
                                <br><hr><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="play">
                                <h5 class="ham">Hamlet -- Saturday June 11th at 7:30PM</h5>
                                <p class="ham"><br>test text</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="line">
                                <br><hr><br>
                            </div>
```

(That isn't all of it but it gets the point across I think).

JQuery currently being used:

```
    $("h5.rnj").click(function() {
        $("p.rnj").toggle();
        
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h5.ham").click(function() {
        $("p.ham").toggle();
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960753/how-to-make-toggle-hidden-by-default#10960868) answer your question?

Comment: Alternatively to adding a class, add `style='display:none;'` to the ones you want to hide at startup

Answer (score 0):

Hide the paragraphs with CSS:

```
p{
    display: none;
}
```